# Run 2 python scripts simultaneously after button pressed

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

I would like to run 2 python scripts (***1.py and 2.py***) simultaneously after button is pressed. How can I do that?

**1.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

**2.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Nice to meet you'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = 5050)
```

**Button.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def Start():
    #run 1.py and 2.py

Button_Start = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start)
Button_Start.pack(side = LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `thread`, And all files should be in same directory.

1 . **first_flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'

def flaskThread1():
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

2 . **second_flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Nice to meet you'

def flaskThread2():
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = 5050)
```

3 . In button running script,

```
import thread
from first_flask import flaskThread1
from second_flask import flaskThread2

#At first button pressed
thread.start_new_thread(flaskThread1,())
thread.start_new_thread(flaskThread2,())
```

Comment: @RahulThanks for helping, however I encountered an error which is ImportError: cannot import name flaskThread1. I do put all files in the same directory.

Comment: @newbie123321 If you face the issue in `second_flask.py`, I updated the code, Try again :)

Comment: @newbie123321 Can you give the full traceback here ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/hello/Button.py", line 3, in <module>
    from first_flask import flaskThread1
ImportError: cannot import name flaskThread1 


@Rahul Here you go

Comment: Just make sure `first_flask.py` is your file and there is a function named `flaskThread1` .